# Kancolle. Song played at the night talk before reassignment to other fleets

Tags: music, kantai-collection

I am very interested what is the name of the song played, when Fubuki and Mutsuki decided to talk to each other during a night walk. Yuudachi with Sendai sisters join them later and all of them make 'Torpedo Soul' pledge. It was just before all of them are going to be reassigned to new fleets.

It was in episode 5. Starts at about 3:20 and ends at 5:11.

I already figured out that composer is most likely to be Natsumi Kameoka (亀岡夏海).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the composer is Natsumi Kameoka. You can find the song in this official OST, [TV Animation "Kantai Collection -Kan Colle-" Original Soundtrack "Kankyo" Vol.1](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/VTCL-60402).

The song is on Disc 2, track #25 titled CHINJU FU (鎮守府) you can hear the sample [here](http://www.neowing.co.jp/product/VTCL-60402/track?from_cdj=1).